Best Practices for Commit/Rollback in Python’s Unit of Work Pattern for Layered Architecture
I have an image below illustrating a layered architecture from the book Architecture Patterns in Python.
Layer architecture image
When implementing this pattern in Python, as shown in the code below, the unit of work is responsible for committing or rolling back transactions in the service layer. Here’s the sample code:
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional
from datetime import date

from allocation.domain import model
from allocation.domain.model import OrderLine
from allocation.service_layer import unit_of_work


class InvalidSku(Exception):
    pass


def is_valid_sku(sku, batches):
    return sku in {b.sku for b in batches}


def add_batch(
    ref: str, sku: str, qty: int, eta: Optional[date],
    uow: unit_of_work.AbstractUnitOfWork,
):
    with uow:
        uow.batches.add(model.Batch(ref, sku, qty, eta))
        uow.commit()


def allocate(
    orderid: str, sku: str, qty: int,
    uow: unit_of_work.AbstractUnitOfWork,
) -> str:
    line = OrderLine(orderid, sku, qty)
    with uow:
        batches = uow.batches.list()
        if not is_valid_sku(line.sku, batches):
            raise InvalidSku(f"Invalid sku {line.sku}")
        batchref = model.allocate(line, batches)
        uow.commit()
    return batchref

As you can see, each function commits within the function itself. My question is: when other services need to use one of these functions, which already commit within themselves, how can I handle rollbacks for transactions that involve several operations?
I usually place commit or rollback in the highest player such as router, so i can call multiple services and commit or rollback, Is my approach incorrect? Should every function implement commit/rollback logic individually, or would that violate the principles of code reuse?
I tried implementing the Unit of Work pattern in the service layer so that each function commits or rolls back within itself. I expected this approach to allow reuse across other services without needing additional rollback logic. However, I realized that if a transaction requires multiple operations from different functions, handling rollbacks becomes challenging. I’m looking for guidance on whether this approach is correct or if there’s a better way to manage multi-operation transactions with commit/rollback logic.
